# How would I make a trigger that will check a value to make sure that it is the correct value or else it would throw up an error?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
 DROP TABLE Officer cascade constraints;
 CREATE TABLE Officer(
 StaffID        Number(6)  PRIMARY KEY,
 FirstName    VARCHAR2(16),
 MiddleName    VARCHAR2(16),
 Surname    VARCHAR2(16),
 Rank    VARCHAR2(16),
 Department    VARCHAR2(16),
 Place_Of_Work   VARCHAR2(16),
 Hire_Date   VARCHAR2(16),
 Inspector_ID    Number(6));

 alter table Officer
  add constraint Officer_Inspector_ID_FK
  foreign key ( Inspector_ID )
  references Officer ( StaffID )
  on delete set null
  ;

 create sequence Officer_seq start with 100 increment by 1 nomaxvalue; 
 create trigger Officer_trigger
 before insert on Officer
 for each row
 begin
 select Officer_seq.nextval into :new.StaffID from dual;
   end;​
```

What I want to do is make it so that if an inspector ID is entered for an officer that doesn't match up to an officer that has the rank of inspector then it will throw an error that states they aren't an inspector & will prompt them to enter a valid ID.

Comment: Read up on Referential Integrity. You don't need a trigger for this.  Here is a link for you - https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=referential%20integrity

Answer (score 1):

no trigger required

What you are describing is a multi-foreign key constraint from  Officer(Inspector_id, Inspector_rank) to Officer(Staff_id, rank)

you need to add the inspector_rank field to officer table

then you need to link both id and rank to officer *together* so they are both the same record

```
foreign key (Inspector_id, Inspector_rank) references Officer(Staff_id, rank)
```

then you need a simple value constraint of inspector_rank CHECK inspector_rank = INSEPECTOR

Comment: I went to do this but my alter table isn't working as I get the error: ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option & I'm not sure why, do you have any idea why this is?

Comment: 3 0.01 alter table Officer DROP CONSTRAINT Officer_Inspector_I ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option -
4 0.01 create sequence Officer_seq start with 100 increment by ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object -
1 0.27 DROP TABLE Officer cascade constraints Table dropped. 0
2 0.08 CREATE TABLE Officer( StaffID Number(6) PRIMARY KEY, Table created. 0
5 0.06 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Officer_trigger before insert on O Trigger created. 0     Those are the errors I get when I run it and I'm not sure what's wrong with it

Comment: not sure... do you have a typo in your constraint name? or is the comment just cut off?

Comment: I'm not sure, what's above is all the code I'm using and that comment are all the results I get when I run it so I'm not sure what's wrong with it.